# JavaFx, ProgressBar and etc

Tags: java, javafx

Ребята, я только осваиваю Джаву и программирование в целом. Прошу помощи.
Нужно создать окно в javaFx и кнопку. При нажатии выходит загрузка от 1 до 100%. 
Прошу не смеяться над столь глупым вопросом, ибо я новичок:)

Comment: Опишите чего хотите добиться, добавьте в статью код который используете, опишите что получается, если вылетает ошибка - то добавьте логи.

Comment: Предполагаю что Ваша ошибка в том, что update для progressbar надо делать в отдельном потоке